# Object's property's value in HTML output not being updated

Tags: javascript, html

Why is my Object's property's value in HTML output not being updated while `console.log(account)` shows that the property is in fact updated when the function is called? I'm using vanilla Javascript. In the screenshot it's the blue underlined number that I'm seeing is not changing when I click the "Proceed with Transaction" button, why is that? I thought that `this.balance = this.balance + x;` will cause the `account.balance` property to change, and it does, but only in the console, why is `document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Current Balance: " + formatMoney(account.balance);`still showing $100.00 even after the `account.change(x)`function is called (by clicking the "Proceed with Transaction button)?

Screenshot:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Project1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Project1</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Welcome to Best Bank.</p>
    <p id="demo1"></p>
    <p id="demo2"></p>
    <form>
        Deposit (+) or Withdraw (-) Amount: <input type="number" id="form_D/W"><br><br>
       
        <button type="button" onclick="account.change(document.getElementById('form_D/W').value*1)">Proceed with Transaction</button>
      </form>
    <p id="demo3"></p>
    
    <script>

        let account = {
            account_number: "1111",
            balance: 100,
            
            change: function (x){
                
                this.balance = this.balance + x;
                console.log("Balance changed.\nPrevious Balance: " + (this.balance - x) + ".\nChanged by " + x + ".\n" + this.balance + " is the current balance.");
                document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Balance changed.<br>Previous Amount: " + formatMoney((this.balance - x)) + ".<br>Changed by " + formatMoney(x) + ".<br>" + formatMoney(this.balance) + " is the current balance."
                
            }
         
        }   
        function formatMoney(number) {
        return number.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
        }
        
        
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Account Number: " + account.account_number;
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Current Balance: " + formatMoney(account.balance);
        
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your change method does not update the `demo2` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Project1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Project1</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Welcome to Best Bank.</p>
    <p id="demo1"></p>
    <p id="demo2"></p>
    <form>
        Deposit (+) or Withdraw (-) Amount: <input type="number" id="form_D/W"><br><br>
       
        <button type="button" onclick="account.change(document.getElementById('form_D/W').value*1)">Proceed with Transaction</button>
      </form>
    <p id="demo3"></p>
    
    <script>

        let account = {
            account_number: "1111",
            balance: 100,
            
            change: function (x){
                
                this.balance = this.balance + x;
                console.log("Balance changed.\nPrevious Balance: " + (this.balance - x) + ".\nChanged by " + x + ".\n" + this.balance + " is the current balance.");
                document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Balance changed.<br>Previous Amount: " + formatMoney((this.balance - x)) + ".<br>Changed by " + formatMoney(x) + ".<br>" + formatMoney(this.balance) + " is the current balance."
                // Updating the element
                document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Current Balance: " + formatMoney(this.balance);
            }
         
        }   
        function formatMoney(number) {
        return number.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
        }
        
        
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Account Number: " + account.account_number;
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Current Balance: " + formatMoney(account.balance);
        
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```